# How to build cloud connector?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, netsuite

I want to build Amazon-Netsuite Connector that will work on both site Data transfer i.e. Copy all the Amazon product into Netsuite and vise-versa, And I want this as a Netsuite Bundle.

Is it required separate UI or It will work in back-end?

But, I am confused, Where to start and how to Initialize this.

Please..Help If you have any idea.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: what is the frequency of your data synchronization? Does it happen based on schedule or on demand ?

Comment: It will  be sync data based on demand

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you would be using MWS and probably the ListMatchingProducts operation on the Amazon side to get the products from them. Calling MWS from a script is possible but it's not very convenient. You may want to look into using a middleware to facilitate the communications and use SuiteTalk instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nlapiRequestURL() to make HTTP requests to MWS APIs from Suitescripts. For Amazon to NetSuite integration, its hard to achieve real time integration as there is no mechanism to write hooks/triggers/user events in Amazon. However, you can easily do Amazon to NetSuite integration in real time.

For products from NetSuite to Amazon you can consider their feed  MWS API  and for Amazon to NetSuite you can consider MWS product API.

You can read the documentation for MWS API [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_Overview.html)

Beware, that the APIs may vary based on your marketplace location.